# for up to four times a year

Tags: prepositions, error

Is "for" used correctly in the following sentence from CNN?

> Unvaccinated people will eventually face a maximum fine of 3,600 euro ($4,000) **for** up to four times a year if they are not on the vaccine register by their assigned vaccination date.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the use is wrong, but the sentence would be better with
*...for up to four times a year...*
replaced by
*...as many as four times a year...*

Comment: But consider "John has been to the museum **for** four times." Is it okay too?

Comment: No, a native speaker would  just say *four times*. *For* would be more likely in, for example, *he's been at the museum for two hours*. But *for* can be used with *times* meaning *instances* - for the nth time, for all the times he's been at the museum, for the third and last time...

Comment: By the same logic, the "for" in the OP sentence should be removed, shouldn't it?

Comment: As I see it, it can be removed, but with the original wording, it gets harder to read.